# Mod auth tkt alternative 2.4

Tags: apache

So we recently moved from httpd 2.2 to 2.4 and it seems as though mod_auth_tkt is no longer available. Is there an alternative to module or a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

From the GitHub repo of Gavin Carr (of *Open Fusion*, and the original author):

https://github.com/gavincarr/mod_auth_tkt

Version 2.3.99b1 (aka 2.4 beta 1) supports Apache httpd-2.4, see
[Gavin's announcement on 2015-07-31](https://sourceforge.net/p/modauthtkt/mailman/message/34334336/) .

The update is based on patches provided by Dietmar Berg, Ivo De Decker and Peter Karman, and aligns `mod_auth_tkt` with the httpd-2.4 API changes. 
There doesn't seem to have been any update since 2015. Dietmar's repo is available here: https://github.com/dietmarb01/mod_auth_tkt , that too was last updated in 2015.

To make the `.rpm` files for a contemporary RHEL/CentOS, assuming you have a viable build system (`gcc`, and `rpmbuild` and the required devel packages):

```
unzip 2.3.99b1.zip        # obtain first from GitHub
cd mod_auth_tkt-2.3.99b1
sed -r -i.bak -e 's_/usr/sbin/apxs_/usr/bin/apxs_'  \
              -e 's_Wed Nov 28 2006_Tue Nov 28 2006_'  \
              -e 's_ ChangeLog _ _'  mod_auth_tkt.spec
cd ..
tar czvf mod_auth_tkt-2.3.99b1.tar.gz mod_auth_tkt-2.3.99b1
rpmbuild -tb mod_auth_tkt-2.3.99b1.tar.gz
```

The three `sed` changes, respectively:

- update the path of `apxs` (which moved into `/usr/bin/` in RHEL 7)
- fix a bogus date which `rpmbuild` will complain about
- handle missing `ChangeLog` file from the git version

Note that the `.spec` file wrongly assigns an architecture to the CGI RPM (which contains only perl and CSS).